# How to add multiple values in JSON object and get an updated json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have the following JSON file

```
var info = [{
     "name" : "john",
     "address" : "32 street, london",
     "contact" : 123456
},{
     "name" : "jeyy",
     "address" : "51 street, new york",
     "contact" : 987654321,
     "gender" : "male"
},{
     "name" : "robert",
     "address" : "14th street, birmingham",
     "contact" : 456123789,
     "gender" : "male"
},{
     "name" : "carlos",
     "address" : "89th street, manchester",
     "contact" : 23456
},{
     "name": "johnny",
     "address": "6th street, Washington",
     "contact": 23456
},{
     "name": "jack",
     "address": "4th street, VA",
     "contact": 23456,
     "gender": "male"
}
];
```

As you can see I am missing "gender" = "male" object in some of the array. How can I add them in the missing object and not add them in an object which already have.
Also how would I get a new updated file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use [.hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) on that object to find out which object don't have property `gender` and iteratively add it and write back into the file again!**

---

Here's a code snippet to help you get started.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

// Promisify fs api(s)
const readFileAsync = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const writeFileAsync = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);

// IIFE to read the file, find the objects which has missing properties, add them and write them back
(async function() {
    try {
        const fileContents = await readFileAsync('data.json');
        const fileData = JSON.parse(fileContents);

        const remainingData = fileData.filter(x => !x.hasOwnProperty('gender'));

        remainingData.forEach(x => x.gender = 'Male');

        await writeFileAsync('data.json', JSON.stringify(fileData, null, 4));

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(`Failed because: {err}!`)
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I use `forEach()` to iterate through the array and check each object if it has a value in `gender` property. If it doesn't then give it a value "male".

```js
var info = [{
     "name" : "john",
     "address" : "32 street, london",
     "contact" : 123456
},{
     "name" : "jeyy",
     "address" : "51 street, new york",
     "contact" : 987654321,
     "gender" : "male"
},{
     "name" : "robert",
     "address" : "14th street, birmingham",
     "contact" : 456123789,
     "gender" : "male"
},{
     "name" : "carlos",
     "address" : "89th street, manchester",
     "contact" : 23456
},{
     "name": "johnny",
     "address": "6th street, Washington",
     "contact": 23456
},{
     "name": "jack",
     "address": "4th street, VA",
     "contact": 23456,
     "gender": "male"
}
];

info.forEach(i => {
  if(!i.gender) i.gender = "male";
});
console.log(info);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve-

```js
var info = [{
    "name" : "john",
    "address" : "32 street, london",
    "contact" : 123456
},{
    "name" : "jeyy",
    "address" : "51 street, new york",
    "contact" : 987654321,
    "gender" : "male"
},{
    "name" : "robert",
    "address" : "14th street, birmingham",
    "contact" : 456123789,
    "gender" : "male"
},{
    "name" : "carlos",
    "address" : "89th street, manchester",
    "contact" : 23456
},{
    "name": "johnny",
    "address": "6th street, Washington",
    "contact": 23456
},{
    "name": "jack",
    "address": "4th street, VA",
    "contact": 23456,
    "gender": "male"
}
];

info.forEach((e)=>{
    var t=Object.keys(e);
   
   if(t.indexOf('gender')==-1)
   e.gender='male';
})
console.log(info);
```